# Limits of multithreaded INSERTS in sqlite

Tags: perl, sqlite

my perl script is multi threaded and in each thread i have to write something to a sqlite3 database. But as you might guess, i get a lot of

> DBD::SQLite::db do failed: database is locked at script.pl line 264.

messages. I read that sqlite3 is able to handle multi threaded situations, even INSERT statements but i think i expect to much when inserting fro 8 threads at the same time.

ok, so its not possible this way but isn't there a possibility to perform a check before inserting to see if the database is locked (or busy) and then wait until is free again?

I really don't want to change to a "real" DBMS cause its only a simple script.

Thank you

Comment: Any code you can post? Multi-threading in Perl has a lot of limitations compared to multi-threading in other languages. I would expect to have to do a lot of acrobatics to get updates to a SQLite db from one thread to be recognized by another thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to block until you can get to the database, try exclusive transactions, i.e.,

```
$dbh->do("begin exclusive transaction") or die $dbh->errstr;
#inserts here
$dbh->do("commit transaction") or die $dbh->errstr;
```

That way, you delegate the locking to SQLite, rather than doing it in Perl. This is safer for all sorts of reasons, not least of which is you might have the database open in something other than Perl, or in another Perl process rather than a thread.

And, as @mob commented, Perl threading is a somewhat funny beast. I'd just get the locking done by the database, where it belongs.

Comment: This is not working for me. Even after adding this i get the "database is locked" warning/error. Even if thats what i should have expected, its not what i need. :) btw, it has to be "$dbh->do("commit") or die $dbh->errstr;" at the end, otherwise i get an syntaxerror.

Comment: Hold on a sec, i think i just did it the wrong way. Will come back later.

Comment: The correct statement for committing should be "commit transaction" and not "commit exclusive transaction", at least here on my Sqlite3 DB.

Answer (score 2):

When writing to a database, SQLite locks the entire database file with fcntl(). When another process/thread tries to write to it, it will wait a set amount of time (30 seconds?) and then give up. See the [SQLiteFAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

Note that while Perl's threads are indeed buggy and weird, that's not the fundamental issue here. I've come to the opinion that SQLite is an inappropriate choice for all but the simplest needs.

Comment: Maybe you are right about sqlite but what are the alternatives? For my purpose it would be to much to use a real RDBMS. What do you use?

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't any, at least as far as I've seen. MySQL is the closest solution.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative might be to have each thread insert into its own staging table, then use `lock` on a variable (a dummy variable is fine) and insert into the final table while the thread has the lock.  In other words, something like...

```
sub ThreadStuff
{
    my $tid=threads->tid;
    #Thread is doing whatever it's doing
    $dbh->do("delete from staging_" . $tid) or die $dbh->errstr;
    $dbh->do("insert into staging_" . $tid . "stuff;") or die $dbh->errstr;

    {
        lock $hall_pass;
        $dbh->do("insert into final_table select * from staging_" . $tid) or die $dbh->errstr;
        #The lock on $hall_pass goes away as soon as we leave this block.
    }
    #Other stuff, maybe cleanup or whatever.
}
```

Comment: Hi Jack, may i ask for an explanation of the code? Why exactly do i need the staging tables? why isn't it possible to block an then insert directly in the main table? Sry if this is a dump question i think i missed something. :)